# good practice for sourcing embedded linux work?

Tags: version-control, embedded-linux

This is probably a really silly question but my work is kind of new to embedded linux, we aren't really sure how we should source our code.

We'll be getting a package from free scale and if it's anything like our omap package it'll prabably be pretty big. Is it a good idea to just source everything, or split it up into different repos, should we leave some stuff out?

We do have some experience with windows ce, we never really sourced everything, just the stuff we used in the board support package and checked it out over the wince600 folder.

Answer (score 0):

There are too many variables to give a definitive answer.

Thus, the correct answer depends on

1. your application and how heavy your changes are
2. your build system

You're talking about freescale and linux embedded, maybe you want to check [openembedded](http://www.openembedded.org/wiki/Main_Page) . If you use this or any similar solution, than you don't need to put under versioning anything but your sources and your recipes.

But if you're customizing the way you build the system, than I'd definitively put the sources and the build scripts under versioning.

Comment: well it depends, we want to get this into team city for nightly builds, I'm guessing we'll only be sourcing what we need to but I'm not sure yet. I'll check out the link later tonight though, thanks!

Comment: I'll second that - your no. #1 problem will be configuration management.  

You might consider commercially supported distributions (although you will pay $$$ for this - but it's probably cheaper than doing it yourself, and definitely cheaper than *not* doing it).  Otherwise you'll be on your own. 

I've been using Angstrom Linux (based on OpenEmbedded) successfully.  This will give you a repeatable environment, but it doesn't come qualified and you might find yourself eating dogfood.  

You absolutely do not need to track the head of Angstrom or any other distro.

Comment: You'll need to satisfy yourself that a particular revision of a distro meets your project's needs and then freeze it there.

Comment: @GodlyManOfGod i never used TeamCity, but what you could do is the following: you put in a repo your application, while the sources that you get in your BSP can be let outside. Than you can script TeamCity so that each time you commit a change in your sources it rebuild your app and creates a new rootfs. My approach to the problem is "let's put under versioning only that code we wrote or changed"

Comment: *let's put under versioning only that code we wrote or changed* Pretty much my approach too. My upstream source is a known version, against which I create patch-sets which I manage with quilt.